# Is this C# generics bug?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

This code is produces the following error:

> Error  1   'ConsoleApplication1.FooBar' does not implement interface member 'ConsoleApplication1.IFoo.Bar'. 'ConsoleApplication1.FooBar.Bar' cannot implement 'ConsoleApplication1.IFoo.Bar' because it does not have the matching return type of 'ConsoleApplication1.IBar'.

```
interface IBar
{

}

interface IFoo
{
    IBar Bar { get; }
}

class FooBar<T> : IFoo where T : IBar
{
    public T Bar
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
}
```

This should not happen because of the where keyword in FooBar class.

I built this with Visual Studio 2013 and .NET 4.5.1.

Comment: In 120% of the cases that I asked myself "Is this a compiler/library bug?", the answer was "**No**".

Comment: Doing IT for 25 years now. ONCE (!) I had a bug that could be traced to a compiler issue (where renaming a variable solved it, an ancient C++ compiler somehow mucked that one up). That is 1 in likely tens of thousands of bugs.

Comment: As a general rule-of-thumb you should remember that the compiler knows how to compile code far better than almost anyone's brain can. The error is almost always in the brain, not the compiler.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This isn't a bug - the return type of the `Bar` property should match exactly i.e. be `IBar`. C# does not support return type covariance.

You could implement the interface explicitly:

```
class FooBar<T> : IFoo where T : IBar
{
    public T Bar
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    IFoo.Bar { get { return this.Bar; } }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not a bug. Since the interface *definition* is not matching the compiler can't implement it. One possibility that would work would be to make `IFoo` also generic, like this:

```
interface IBar
{
}

interface IFoo<T>
{
    T Bar { get; }
}

class FooBar<T> : IFoo<T> where T : IBar
{
    public T Bar
    {
        get { return default(T); }
    }
}
```